# Is there a way to count group and subgroup using OVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table with some information about countries including:

```
City Name | Province | Country | ...

Honolulu       HI        US
Hilo           HI        US
Kihei          HI        US
Annapolis      MD        US
Laurel         MD        US
Sidney         LD        AU
Camberra       PP        AU
Darwin         PP        AU
...
```

And I want my query to look like this (preferably using OVER function to spare performance):

```
Country | Count_C | Province | Count_P
US           5         MD         2
US           5         HI         3
AU           3         LD         1
AU           3         PP         2
...
```

I've already managed doing this, but not without losing performance with some subqueries (the query took very long to run in the large table)

Bad Code:

```
SELECT country_name                              AS Country
      ,Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name) AS Count_C
      ,province                                  AS Province
      ,Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY province)     AS Count_P
FROM country_list
GROUP BY country_name
        ,province
ORDER BY 1 DESC
        ,4 DESC
```

Comment: Slight detour....https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want aggregation with one window function:

```
SELECT country_name as Country,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country_name) as country_cnt,
       province,
       Count(*) as province_count
FROM country_list
GROUP BY country_name, province
ORDER BY Country DESC, Province DESC;
```

Comment: Why did you decide to use ordinal positions here, Gordon, and not the column aliases?

Comment: @Larnu . . . I left them from the OP's question.  Changing them didn't seem relevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Thanks! It does work, but you forgot the commas in the select statement though.